# jQuery check single select if same name but multipled if same values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys i just want to ask on how to deal with checking a `checkbox` with the same name but have different values

For example,

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="my_name" values="1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="my_name" values="2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="my_name" values="2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="my_name" values="3"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="my_name" values="3"/>
```

All I want is: If I check the one with values = 1 only that will be checked, if I check values with 2 the 1 will be unchecked and all with values of 2 will be checked, same as with three then all 3 will be checked while all 2 will be unchecked.

Please help, thank you :)

Comment: If you're wanting to check individual checkboxes, the `name` attribute has to be unique for each `input` field.

Comment: @JoshSpears its not individually, this checkboxes are grouped, but if I want check a name with different value the last checkbox with different value will be unchecked

Comment: You need to use radio for this functionality.

Comment: Then like @AnuragSinghBisht said, `type="radio"` is what you need.

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the changed input's siblings for other inputs with that value and set their `checked` attribute to `true`, and similarly set `checked` to `false` for siblings with different values:

```js
$('[name=my_name]').on('change', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.siblings('[value='+this.value+']').prop('checked', true)
  $this.siblings('[value!='+this.value+']').prop('checked', false)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1 <input type="checkbox" name="my_name" value="1"/>
2 <input type="checkbox" name="my_name" value="2"/>
2 <input type="checkbox" name="my_name" value="2"/>
3 <input type="checkbox" name="my_name" value="3"/>
3 <input type="checkbox" name="my_name" value="3"/>
```

Comment: Thank you mate :) very awesome

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help! Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

Multiple input type cannot have the same name , but can have same class name. Instead of checking the name attr cheak instead class attr.